# Counting value from CSV in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv

How to count differents values from a CSV to a new CSV or JSON in javascript?

like this .csv:

```
outbound;API1;Restitution;1.0
outbound;API1;Restitution;1.0
outbound;API1;Operations;1.0
outbound;API2;Operations;2.0
outbound;API2;Operations;2.0
outbound;API3;Service;1.0
```

to this one :

```
API1,3
API2,2
API3,1
```

I did this in python but I need it in JS now :

```
import csv
from glob import glob

myDict = {}
filename = glob('*.csv')[0]     #take any .csv file
row_number = 0

with open(filename, 'rU') as f:     #arg 'r' for reading and 'U' for Universal, can read .csv without quotes.
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        row_number +=1
        if row[1] in myDict:
            myDict[row[1]] += 1
        else:
            myDict[row[1]] = 1

data = open("output.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(data)
for word in myDict:
    data = word, float(myDict[word])/row_number*100
    w.writerow(data)
```

Comment: LMGTFY https://www.google.ca/search?ei=KlkEWsHFHMyUjwS30qvYDg&q=javascript+csv+library&oq=javascript+csv+l&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l2j0i22i30k1l8.21677.23260.0.24725.5.5.0.0.0.0.185.700.0j5.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.692...0i67k1.0.N8uLEWpvJH8

Comment: thanks but badly I can't succeed doing it with papa parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your file into an array of strings like:

```
[
  'outbound;API1;Restitution;1.0',
  'outbound;API1;Restitution;1.0',
  'outbound;API1;Operations;1.0',
  'outbound;API2;Operations;2.0',
  'outbound;API2;Operations;2.0',
  'outbound;API3;Service;1.0'
]
```

You can write a function to format it like:

```
function formatData(data) {
  var formattedData = [];

  data.map(
    (str) => {
      var formattedString = str.split(';')[1] + ',' + data.filter((d) => d.split(';')[1] === str.split(';')[1]).length;
      if (formattedData.indexOf(formattedString) === -1)
        formattedData.push(formattedString);
    }
  );

  return formattedData;
}
```

And call it like ...

```
formatData(d);
```

It will return

```
["API1,3", "API2,2", "API3,1"]
```

Comment: ahah I don't have enough reputation to do it sorry, by the way If I want to use your method for a bigger file with something like 100k lines ? How to proceed ?